# From the skellam distribution to the gaussian

Tags: central-limit-theorem

How do I reach to continous limit of a skellam distribution and obtain a gaussian distribution for the unbiased case?
>

Comment: I have never heard about "Skellam distribution", and I think this is the case for many people even well versed in probability. Could you give at least a reference ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution, it's the distribution of the difference between two poisson processes

Comment: Fisz M (1953). “The Limiting Distribution of the Difference of Two Poisson Random Variables.” Zastosowania Mat, 1, 41–45.